# find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, cron

I am trying to find some files on a path `/local/java_apps/` and then delete them using a shell script and generate a log file in the `/home/jboss`
The code is as follows :

```
STAMP=$(date +"%m%d%Y%H%M%S")
sudo -u jboss find /local/java_apps/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -mtime +180 -print -delete >> /home/jboss/.log_$STAMP 2>&1
```

The `ls -ld /local/java_apps` command gives:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 10 2017 /local/java_apps/
```

The crontab looks like this:

```
0 1 * * 4 /etc/cron.weekly/servercleanup.sh
```

When the script is run by the crontab it gives the following error:

```
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you paste output of `ls -ld /local/java_apps` ?

Comment: Output : drwxrwxr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 10 2017 /local/java_apps/

Comment: The permissions are 775 not 777. That's why user `jboss` cannot delete files from this folder.

Answer (score 12):

`find` changes its directory as part of its internal operation. When you run the command, you're sitting in a directory that the `jboss` user doesn't have permission to go to, so when `find` tries to put its directory back to what it was, it fails. To fix the problem, run the command from a directory that `jboss` is allowed to access.

Comment: If you're talking about the command "sudo -u" in /etc/cron.weekly/ the shell file has the owner root with 777 access. So jboss already has access to that path

Comment: @YashGandhi I'm talking about your current working directory when you run the command, not the directory that it's in.

Comment: Wow, this sucks REALLY bad. How is it possible that such a core tool has this issue?

Comment: @AFP_555 Is this really a big issue? Why do you need to run `find` from a directory that you don't have permission to enter? If it's really a big deal for some reason, you could see about sending upstream patches to make it use the `*at` functions instead.